# Contribution of each variable in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

What will be the best measure of the contribution of a variable in multiple linear regression? I was thinking of using the coefficient ratio as a marker of a variable's contribution.

**For example:**

If the equation is $$Y_{predicted}=a_1X_1+a_2X_2+a_3$$

Then $X_1$'s contribution can be written down as:
$$\frac{a_1}{a_1+a_2+a_3}$$
Is there some other method possible to write down the contribution. Since in this case if any coefficient is negative, there is a possibility that a variable's contribution exceeds $100\%$.

Comment: How about $\frac{a_1^2}{a_1^2+a_2^2}$, which measures how much the gradient is in the $X_1$ direction? In most contexts $a_3$ is probably not that relevant, since it's just a common offset.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes I had that in mind too. But I was looking for something on the lines of t-Test.

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesn't work unless your variables have been normalized to 1, and are positive.

The usual way to do what you describe is to do an ["ANOVA"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#ANOVA_for_multiple_factors), looking at the variance for each term and its contribution to the whole variance. A very easy example (especially with few variables) is the $R^2$, the "fit" of your model.

You can look at the correlation as well (the higher the correlation in **absolute value** the more explaining power).

Lastly, you can check the principal component analysis, which will help you select the combination of variables that has the most explanatory power.